# creating multiple header with setHeaderFooter

Tags: r

[setHeaderFooter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ModTs.png)

setHeaderFooter(wb1, sheet = "sheet", firstHeader = c("leftheader1", "centerheader1", "rightheader1"), footer = c("leftfooter", "centerfooter, "rightfooter"))

Comment: Issue- I want to create multiple headers but couldn't get the result with the below code.
I am only able to create one header

Comment: I would like to generate the headers as below.

leftheader1     Centerheader1    rightheader1   
leftheader2     centerheader2    rightheader2
leftheader3

Comment: please help with the code

Comment: Please edit your question and add your explanations there. Also, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and don't post code as images.